# What happens when grep in Cygwin tries to read contents of windows exe file?

Tags: grep

As I know it, grep should not kick off an executable.
But while running grep recursively through sub-directories on a hard drive while within Cygwin on a Windows machine, it kicked off an executable called "FastMailChecker v. 1.0.exe"
The exe ran and then deleted itself.

How is this possible? 
I got a "permission denied" error but not because it couldn't read the exe. It looks like the error is from when the exe tried to do something on my workstation.
In either case, the file "FastMailChecker v. 1.0.exe" deleted itself after grepping on it

Any explanation how this could have happened? 
I have the original zip files for these directories and I am able to reproduce the above scenario.

Comment: What are the exact steps to reproduce the scenario? In particular, what is the command you use to "run grep recursively through sub-directories on a hard drive"? Please [edit] the question and be specific.

Comment: Hi, the command I ran was  

"grep -irf checklist.txt test.area > ouput.txt"

The test.area folder contains about 30+ directories, each one has text files